# how to perform hough transformation for spesific angle range

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have been trying to detect and track vehicle in a video stream. Recently I decided to implement a hard-coded method which find out the shadow of a vehicle and detect entire vehicle with respect to tire position. At the end, I partially done with my implementation. Here is the [video link](https://youtu.be/ffToAgwssMc) of demonstration.

At the first step I used canny edge detector to subtract edge of the video frames.

[image]

Then I used hough transform funciton in opencv.

[image]

However this functions finds all the horizontal and vertical lines while I only interested in horizontal lines which are possibly shadow of the vehicle.

[image]

My question is how I can use hough line transform function where it only checks the lines which are in a spesific range of angle and within a spesific area. Is there any parameter that tresholds the angle ? Or should I implement the function by myself ?

Comment: Or you can just use opencv hough implementation, keep only the lines with the desired angle and discard the others...

Answer (score 1):

Since you end up with a binary image after the Canny operation, it may be easiest to convolve the image with a simple horizontal Prewitt operator before applying the Hough transform:

```
 1    1    1
 0    0    0
-1   -1   -1
```

which will give you a map of the grayscale intensities of each pixel, with pixels along horizontal edge giving the strongest signal. The advantage of using only the horizontal operator is that vertical edges receive no amplification, horizontal edges receive maximum amplification, and any edge within 45° of horizontal should have a signal somewhere between the two. You can use the resulting image to decide which pixels from the Canny mask to keep when you apply the detect edges to the original image: If the Prewitt signal is above a certain threshold for a pixel, that pixel is assumed to be along a 'horizontal-enough' edge that gets kept, discard otherwise. I believe opencv has this feature, but it's trivial to implement if not.